# how to display the title in the middle of a donut chart with legend?(react-highcharts)

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I know how to centered it by use this option:

```
 title: {
    text: "This is title",
    align: "center",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
  },
```

it works fine , but when there is a legend aligned in right or left , it will not perfectly displayed in the center , to add a x position to adjust it is ok ,but not responsive. when you change the window size , it will has some offsets.

here is the demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118

I tried use load/redraw to adjust it , but I don't know why it not work when I bind redraw function to react component, I will do some further action in it so I can't define it when I create the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position a title in a `render` callback function:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var seriesElPos = this.seriesGroup.getBBox();

            this.title.attr({
                x: seriesElPos.width / 2 + seriesElPos.x
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4760/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render